# How to inject bean via generic variable in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have problem with injecting bean with generic types. Look at the example. I will inject to the service a repository which types takes from App class. Now i have exception:

*No qualifying bean of type 'asd.IRepository' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b*

asd here is package, just for tests.

What can I do in this situation? Is any way to makes it?

```
public interface IRepository<T, V> {
    void print();
}


@Component
public class A implements IRepository<String,String> {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

@Component
public class B implements IRepository<Double,String> {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

@Service
public class ServiceABC<V, T> {

    @Autowired
    private IRepository<V,T> repo;

    public void print(){
        repo.print();
    }
}

@Controller
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceABC<String, String> serviceABC;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("asd");

        App app = ctx.getBean(App.class);
        app.serviceABC.print();
    }
```

Comment: Is the `ServiceABC` class necessary?

Comment: This is basic example. In production service does some magic :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't know in advance which implementation of your `IRepository` interface you will need. And you will know that at runtime. In this case it is a typical case for Factory pattern where you will have a `IRepositoryFactory` that will have a method thhat retrieves specific implementation by type (for example `IRepositoryFactory.getInstance(String type);` So in your `ServiceABC` you may use the `IRepository` to get specific bean at runtime. So Factory pattern may be an answer to your question. I also wrote an article that deals with this type of problem and proposes the idea of self-populating Factory (using Open source library that provides such utility). Here is the link to the article: [Non-intrusive access to "Orphaned" Beans in Spring framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-intrusive-access-orphaned-beans-spring-framework-michael-gantman/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your components and autowire by name:

```
@Component("A")
public class A implements IRepository<String,String> {...}

@Component("B")
public class B implements IRepository<Double,String> {...}

[...]

@Autowired
@Qualifier("B")
private IRepository repo;
```

Comment: This example is only my homemade code. I can't name this property becouse i dont know what I will inject at the moment. Its very generic class

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
@Controller
public class RepositoryFactory {

    @Autowired
    private IRepository<String, String> a;

    @Autowired
    private IRepository<Double, String> b;

    public IRepository getRepository(String className) {

        if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            return a;
        } else if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            return b;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

@Service
public class ServiceABC {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory;

    public void print(String className){
        repositoryFactory.getRepository(className).print();
    }
}


@Controller
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceABC serviceABC;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("asd");

        App app = ctx.getBean(App.class);
        app.serviceABC.print(A.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}s
```

Comment: Well, you got the idea right, but the implementation is very primitive. Method public IRepository getRepository(String className) should be static, and your factory would have to be updated every time you add another implementation. I suggest that you read the article that I mentioned in my answer and check the open source library that is mentioned there. It already solves all the problems. Also you can see the source code. Also thanks for choosing my answer as the resolving answer, but if it is so could you also up-vote it? ;)